# How can I catch exit codes of a command on a bitbake recipe?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have a bitbake recipe in which I need to check for the availability of a remote server before downloading some packages from it. For that, I use ping as below:

```
ping ${HOST} -c1 -w4 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "ERROR: Unable to reach ${HOST}. Exiting now with code $?..."
    exit $? 
fi
```

The code above works just fine in a terminal, and I get the corresponding exit codes: 0 for OK and nonzero for NOK.

However, the exact same code on a bitbake recipe, the exit code `$?` is always empty. Instead, bitbake itself will catch the error code, and the execution will continue. It will fail much later, when trying to unpack the not-downloaded files. At that point, I get a warning about the nonzero exit code thrown by `ping` much earlier. Currently that is how it looks like:

```
if [ "$(ping ${HOST} -c1 -w4 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null)" = 0 ]; then
    echo "ERROR: Unable to reach ${HOST}. Exiting now..."
    exit 1 
fi

# Some other stuff here...

ar -x ${BUILDDIR}/tmp/deploy/ipk/all/rheas_*.ipk
```

And I get:

```
ERROR: rheas-0.0-r0 do_compile: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /data/oe-core/build/tmp/work/armv5te-poky-linux-gnueabi/rheas/0.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.2239)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /data/oe-core/build/tmp/work/armv5te-poky-linux-gnueabi/rheas/0.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.2239
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| ar: /data/oe-core/build/tmp/deploy/ipk/all/rheas_*.ipk: No such file or directory
| WARNING: exit code 9 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /data/retail-renos-oe-core/build/tmp/work/armv5te-poky-linux-gnueabi/rheas/0.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.2239)
ERROR: Task (/data/oe-core/meta-renos/recipes-core/rheas/rheas_0.0.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
```

In summary, I can not use the exit codes myself, because it seems that bitbake is hijacking it somehow.

The issue with that is that I can't throw a user friendly error, and others never knows where the problem comes from.

So my question is: how can I use exit codes inside a bitbake recipe?

In this project specifically I am using bitbake version 1.32.0.

This answer does not seem to be in the manual.

Comment: Please include your recipe or at least the whole function and the actual error message or result you get. I've made an answer but it is partly guesswork...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

bitbake uses the safer `set -e` by default: the script execution stops on first error.

You could disable this (with `set +e`) but I suggest handling the single known-to-fail command specifically instead. There's a few ways you can do it, here's an example (this also fixes a bug in your code where you used the exit value of echo as your exit value):

```
err=0
ping ${HOST} -c1 -w4 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null || err=$?
if [ $err -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "ERROR: Unable to reach ${HOST}. Exiting now with code $err..."
    exit $err 
fi
```

Comment: That did the job. Thanks!!